# I'm eligible to stay 90 days in Schengen out of 180, but can I also stay 90 days in Romania, or are the days there concurrent with the Schengen days?

Tags: schengen, visa-free-entry, australian-citizens, romania, 90-180-visa-rules

I'm an Australian citizen and I've been in Schengen over 70 days visa free, out of 90 days that I'm permitted to stay.

I know Romania (and Bulgaria) are part of the EU but not yet part of Schengen, but that they have been mirroring the Schengen 90/180 visa policy for some years already.

But what's unclear is whether Romania considers days that you've used up in the Schengen Area to also be used up for Romania.

In other words, if I went to Romania in the next week or so would I be able to stay there just until my 90 Schengen days finish, or would I begin a fresh 90 days that I'm permitted to spend in Romania?

Wikipedia doesn't have a separate visa policy page for Romania or Bulgaria but the Wikipedia page on Schengen visa policy just mentioned that they have some kind of mirroring of the Schengen rules without clarifying what that actually means.

Comment: My understanding is that they are indeed counted separately (both ways), but I'm curious to see someone confirm this. Also, note the specific rules for Australian citizens: " Australia nationals can spend up to 90 days in **each** of Austria, Belgium, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Iceland, Italy, Luxembourg, The Netherlands, Norway, and Sweden without reference to time spent in other Schengen signatory states", if that's the reason you wan to exit the Schengen Area

Comment: Wow I never heard that before! Where is it from?

Comment: In the very small text in the "Rules for the Annex II nationals" box on the Wikipedia [Visa policy of the Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Nationals_of_'Annex_II'_countries_and_territories_(visa_waiver_countries)) page.

Comment: @jcaron: Aha that was much easier to find after moving from the phone to the laptop (-: But how would they know how much time you've been in a particular country given that there are no border checks?

Comment: No idea, and I expect this to be non-trivial and involve entering and exiting directly from outside Schengen into the relevant countries. See the answer [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122146/how-can-i-stay-more-than-90-180-days-in-schengen-using-australias-bilateral-agr) for a similar situation. Note that you will probably need to get written confirmation of this in advance in some form that is likely to convince passport control officers, many probably apply the 90/180 rule and not much else and will probably need some convincing.

Comment: @hippietrail These 'extensions' are usually rooted in pre-schengen agreements between individual countries, which still apply and you are right that it is difficult to control that the rules are followed. Be aware though, that the time you spend in these countries are counted towards the time you are allowed to spend in *other* Schengen countries, so if you e.g. spend 50 days in Austria and directly thereafter 50 days in Germany, you would not be allowed to go to, transit or exit the Schengen area from Italy (which does not grant you any extra 'allowance').